# How to check if the cell inside the CSV file has a comma using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I'd like to know on how I can check if the cell inside my CSV file has a comma, so that I can then replace it with white space. Below is the image of my CSV file:
[My CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEJSx.jpg)

Here is my C# code:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fName))
{
    System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fName);
    do
    {
        textLine = objReader.ReadLine();
        if (textLine != "")
        {
            splitLine = textLine.Split(',');
            if (splitLine[0] != "" || splitLine[1] != "")
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(splitLine);
            }
        }
    } while (objReader.Peek() != -1);
}
return true;
```

Below is the result of the above code.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0INK0.jpg)

Instead of **Blk 32, Lot 3**, the **Lot 3** got separated due to the comma after the **Blk 32**. I want them to become one as **Blk 32, Lot 3**.

Comment: I recommend parsing CSV files using the [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: Did you have a look at the CSV file in Notepad, for example? How do you think the comma within the cell is exported to a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

I think for your case, it's better to add `quotation marks` around your columns when exporting to csv in Excel. You then can use regex to get those matching column data.

http://www.lenashore.com/2012/04/how-to-add-quotes-to-your-cells-in-excel-automatically/

Comment: +1, if your data can contain commas, quote your values. Otherwise consider an alternate delimiter separated value format. (I.e. pipes "|")

Answer (score 0):

As this happened due to the presence of comma in csv files which is marked be enclosing it in quotation marks, it can be solved be tracking these quotation mark terms and merge them like this:

```
splitLine = textLine.Split(',');
List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
for (i = 0; i < splitLine.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (splitLine[i] != "" && splitLine[i + 1] != "" && splitLine[i][0] == '"' && splitLine[i + 1][splitLine[i + 1].Length - 1] == '"')
    {
        tmp.Add(splitLine[i] + "," + splitLine[i + 1]);
        i++;
    }
    else
    tmp.Add(splitLine[i]);
}
splitLine = tmp.ToArray();
```